# gsutil Parallel Composite Uploads using Firebase Auth

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-storage

I am developing an Electron app that uses Firebase authentication. Users will be uploading 500mb+ files. I would like to use gsutil cp command to enable Parallel Composite Uploads. Am I able to use Firebase auth token with gsutil? I read that a service account can be impersonated by an authenticated user, does this apply to Firebase?

Answer (score 0):

Please note that [**the gsutil**](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil) is a Python application that lets you access Google Cloud Storage from the command line. You can use gsutil to do a wide range of bucket and object management tasks, including:

- Creating and deleting buckets.
- Uploading, downloading, and deleting objects.
- Listing buckets and objects. Moving, copying, and renaming objects.
- Editing object and bucket ACLs.

The [**gcloud command-line interface**](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud) is the primary CLI tool to create and manage Google Cloud resources. You can use this tool to perform many common platform tasks either from the command line or in scripts and other automations.

It seems to me that the token generated from the Firebase console is not used to [authenticate to Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/authentication) directly. Instead, I believe that it is a [Firebase ID token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/auth?authuser=1#firebase_id_tokens) and thus, you will not be able to generate it with gsutil.

According to the **[Official Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/authentication#gsutilauth)**, for gsutil authentication, you have to use the [following command](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/activate-service-account):

- **gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file KEY_FILE**

Regarding your other question, **the Firebase Authentication client-side SDKs** have no built-in impersonation mechanism. To sign in as a specific user on these SDKs, you must know that user's credentials.

However, impersonation of a user is supported by the **Firebase Admin SDK's** in its interaction with the Realtime Database. As the Admin SDK is meant to be run in a trusted environment with administrative privileges.

Please have a look into the [Official Documentation for impersonating a regular user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/start#authenticate-with-limited-privileges).